# Difficulties creating dataframe out of 180 xml files

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I have around 180 xml files that are in a list `xml_files`. Now I need to iterate through those files, and combine them in 1 pandas dataframe. All xml files follow the same structure.

Can someone help me out with my code, I'm stuck at the point where I need to create 1 dataframe out of all the xml files. The `doc` variable contains the right structure that I need from the xml file.

```
import xmltodict
import pandas as pd
import glob

xml_files = [i for i in glob.glob('*.xml')]
for file in xml_files:
    with open(file) as f:
        doc = xmltodict.parse(f.read())['FMPDSORESULT']["ROW"]
```

Sample data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This grammar has been deprecated - use FMPXMLRESULT instead -->
-<FMPDSORESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
<ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
<DATABASE>FrontEnd.fmp12</DATABASE>
<LAYOUT/>

-<ROW RECORDID="181035" MODID="0">
<identificatie>GAC</identificatie>
<naam>Sample name</naam>
<wachtwoord>ww</wachtwoord>
<kenmerk>km</kenmerk>
<timestamp>1-4-2020 16:10:05</timestamp>
<berichtversie>1.0</berichtversie>
<analysecode>BPsz200330091</analysecode>
<datum>1-4-2020</datum>
<datumontvangst>30-3-2020</datumontvangst>
<klantcode>200</klantcode>
<opdrachtgever>Opdrachtgever 1</opdrachtgever>
<produkt>Sample product</produkt>
<produktnaam>Sample name</produktnaam>
<varieteit>Sample variety</varieteit>
<leverancier>Sample leverancier</leverancier>
<land_van_herkomst>Sample land</land_van_herkomst>
<monster_code>38301</monster_code>
<traceability_code/>
<component>Perchlorate</component>
<methode>Perchloraat</methode>
<eenheid>mg/kg</eenheid>
<gehalte><0.01</gehalte>
<MRL/>
<LAND/>
<MRLBL>EU</MRLBL>
<as_ARfD/>
<as_ARfD_DE/>
<monsternamelocatie/>
<AantalComponenten>0</AantalComponenten>
<component_EN>Perchlorate</component_EN>
<ggn_gln>87237929290</ggn_gln>
<teler/>
<perceel/>
<retailnorm/>
<blacklisted/>
<herkomstlandcode>TST</herkomstlandcode>
<merk/>
</ROW>

-<ROW RECORDID="181036" MODID="0">
<identificatie>GAC</identificatie>
<naam>Sample Name</naam>
<wachtwoord>ww</wachtwoord>
<kenmerk>km</kenmerk>
<timestamp>1-4-2020 16:10:05</timestamp>
<berichtversie>1.0</berichtversie>
<analysecode>dsdsds</analysecode>
<datum>1-4-2020</datum>
<datumontvangst>30-3-2020</datumontvangst>
<klantcode>200</klantcode>
<opdrachtgever>Sample opdrachtgever</opdrachtgever>
<produkt>Sample product</produkt>
<produktnaam>Sample productnaam</produktnaam>
<varieteit>Sample variety</varieteit>
<leverancier>Sample leverancier</leverancier>
<land_van_herkomst>TST</land_van_herkomst>
<monster_code>312345</monster_code>
<traceability_code/>
<component>Chlorate</component>
<methode>Perchloraat</methode>
<eenheid>mg/kg</eenheid>
<gehalte><0.01</gehalte>
<MRL/>
<LAND/>
<MRLBL>EU</MRLBL>
<as_ARfD/>
<as_ARfD_DE/>
<monsternamelocatie/>
<AantalComponenten>0</AantalComponenten>
<component_EN>Chlorate</component_EN>
<ggn_gln>87491070</ggn_gln>
<teler/>
<perceel/>
<retailnorm/>
<blacklisted/>
<herkomstlandcode>TST</herkomstlandcode>
<merk/>
</ROW>

</FMPDSORESULT>
```

Expected output is a dataframe with attributes names as column headers and attribute values as rows. Below an example of the first few columns

[image]

Comment: whats the expected output of your dataframe?

Comment: @sammywemmy  I edited the post at the bottom, hope this is enough for you to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that is to use `pd.concat`, as follows. Please note that some of the XML documents were invalid, and required preprocessing. Also, I had to distinguish between documents with a single row and documents with multiple rows.

```
import glob 
import re

frames = []

xml_files = [i for i in glob.glob('*.xml')]
for file in xml_files:
    with open(file) as f:
        text = f.read()
        # fix malformed XML 
        text = text.replace("\n-", "\n")
        text = re.sub(r"><([^/])", ">\\1", text)

        doc = xmltodict.parse(text)['FMPDSORESULT']["ROW"]
        if isinstance(doc, list):
            doc_df = pd.DataFrame(doc)               # multiple rows 
        else:
            doc_df = pd.DataFrame(doc, index = [0])    # single row 
        frames.append(doc_df)
res = pd.concat(frames)
```

The result, with fake data of course, would be:

[image]

You can now extract the columns that you'd like to use for future processing.

Comment: Hi Roy, I get the following error: cannot concatenate object of type ''; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: Emm. Seems like the xml wasn’t parsed well. Could you please print ‘doc’ before you try to concat it?

Comment: Printing the doc will stream the data. I tried out yielding the doc as a generator object but I'm new to Python so that didn't work out

Comment: What I would try is to start with very simple code and a handful of xml docs. Start there, see that it works, and then make it more efficient / complete.

Comment: Hi Roy, in order for your suggestion to work I changed doc to ```doc = pd.DataFrame([xmltodict.parse(f.read())['FMPDSORESULT']["ROW"]])``` which works. Now I figured out what goes wrong. When an XML files contains more than 1 row it does not append to the dataframe

Comment: Any idea how I should modify code in order for it to work?

Comment: Aha!  My bad. I changed something when copying the code. I’ll change it. Sorry. (And if you found the answer helpful, it would be great if you could accept it for future generations)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215899/discussion-between-luukv93-and-roy2012).

Answer (score 1):

Consider building a list of dictionaries using Python's built-in XML library. Since your XML includes a default namespace, map to a defined prefix like `doc`. Then outside loop, concatenate all data frames together.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def proc_xml(file):
    with open(file) as f:
         txt = f.read()

         # CLEAN UP INVALID TOKENS
         dom = ET.fromstring(txt.replace('\n-', '\n').replace('><', '>&lt;'))

         nmsp = {'doc': 'http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult'}

         # COMBINE ATTRIBUTE AND VALUES IN ONE LIST OF DICTS 
         # DICT MERGE SYNTAX WORKS Python 3.5+
         data = [{**r.attrib, **{el.tag.split('}')[1]: el.text 
                                 for el in r.findall('*')}
                 } for r in dom.findall('.//doc:ROW', nmsp)]

         return pd.DataFrame(data)


df_list = [proc_xml(f) for f in glob.glob('*.xml')]

final_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Comment: Interesting pattern, especially I like the way you use a function in a list comprehension to construct the df list and concat them afterwards.